# Dynamic data result based on the string query in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get and display the data based on the string query, like I don't need to do a dto. Like typically do in C# & ASP.NET.

Example in normal process

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM People"

var connection = _context.connection.GetDatabase();
var result = connection.query<DTONAME>{query};
```

Here the question: how can I get a result or dynamic without being dependent into the `dtoName`, because currently in my frontend, I have a design that if I click that name it can display the data on the model, that why I need to know if possible to get a dynamic result in the C# without using the dto which we know to used for container of the value

Also what type of method should I use because the result of that controller will display to a dynamic modal too?

C#, ASP.NET and react js

I am still currently investigating and researching, I tried some ideas but still need a dto to run.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? / In Sql Server you can use [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=json-path). Execute `SELECT * FROM People FOR JSON AUTO` and return result as string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, before it was common to "have" a data model (some type of class built around using a ORM), then often we just used a datatable. So, our industry for 20+ year often just used the database tables for the data sources in the applcation.

So, say I want to display some Hotel information.

Then I can have say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="120px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdView" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="btn myshadow"
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click"
                    OnClientClick="myhide();"  >                
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> View
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my code to load can be say this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";


        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();    
    }
```

Now, one will fast find that typing SQL command object, and conneciton code over and over, so I have a static "general" code module with a few helpers.

In above, I used MyRst, and that was this:

```
    public static DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

            

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                rstData.TableName = strSQL;
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

So, all the above does is pull a sql query into a data table.

The result of above GridView is thus this:

[image]

And I can use my helper routines to say edit or view a row.

The button click code for above is say this:

```
    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        int PK = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
            new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @PK");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@PK", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK;

        DataTable rstRowPick = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);

        // load one reocrd into page etc.

    }
```

So, once again, when the user clicks on a row, then we pull the one row from the database based on the PK value from the database.

So, these so called "database first" types of applications? Well, they never did have any object modeling system, and for 20+ years, most desktop software was written this way. And in fact, quite a few older web sites also used the above approach, and often the extra moving parts of a ORM and having a class for each table is not worth the efforts.

So, I have a "few" helper routines, like MyRst("some sql"), or MyRstP (some Sqlcommand object that supports paratmers) etc.

So, MyRstP is simular, but takes a sql command object in place of raw sql, and was this:

```
public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

And I have one for simple execute of sql commands and a few more such helpers. With a few helpers, you find writing code to pull data rather easy.